# Go Back N on SDN based Network

Tags: sdn, go-back-n

is it possible to implement GBN conjestion window in SDN based network, while we have 2 possible routes (through R1 or R2) from the clinet to the server and we want to use both of them to increase tcp performance.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. I do not see what this question has to do with programming. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In general, No you can't.

Go Back N is a layer 4 protocol and hence only devices running Layer 4 (i.e. end hosts) will be able to interact.

This is not related to what type of network you are using.